# LINQ against two different data contexts using interfaces

Tags: c#, linq, generics, interface

This is the continuation of my question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718748/linq-against-dynamic-object).

**Brief summary:** I have two different databases with minimal changes (one table and foreign keys to it are missing in one table) and I want my import utility that uses Linq-To-Sql to be able to populate both databases with data without duplication of the logic.

My first approach was to use `dynamic` storing two different database contexts in a single variable, but this approach did not work and I was recommended to use interfaces for this purpose.

Now I bumped into the following problem:

I correctly extracted interfaces from my db context class:

```
public interface IDataContext
{
    System.Data.Linq.Table<IFieldCollection> FieldCollections { get; }
    System.Data.Linq.Table<IField> Fields { get; }
}
```

... but in order to be able to implement the interface by two different database context classes I had to substitute the actual LINQ classes (`FieldCollection`, `Field`) with interfaces as well.

Now I have problems with returning `Table<IFieldCollection>` or `Table<IField>` in my class implementation. The auto-generated code for the db context class is the following:

```
    public System.Data.Linq.Table<FieldCollection> FieldCollections
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetTable<FieldCollection>();
        }
    }
```

So, in order to implement `IDataContext` here I need to change the returning value to `Table<IFieldCollection>`. How can I then cast `Table<FieldCollection>` to `Table<IFieldCollection>` in my property getter *without retrieving the complete table from the database*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my testapp the following seems to work.

Define your interface like this:

```
public interface IDataContext {
    IQueryable<IFieldCollection> FieldCollections { get; }
    IQueryable<IField> Fields { get; }
}
```

Update your datacontexts with the following implementation:

```
public partial class DataContext1: IDataContext {
    IQueryable<IFieldCollection> IDataContext.FieldCollections { 
        get { return FieldCollections; }
    }
    IQueryable<IField> IDataContext.Fields { 
        get { return Fields; }
    }
}
```

Now, if you query for example, using a `.Where(<predicate>).FirstOrDefault()` then the query is compiled correctly, with a corresponding WHERE  in SQL.

```
using (IDataContext context = MyDataContextFactory.GetInstance() /* or something else */) {
    var fieldsCount = context.Fields.Where(x => x.Id == 1).Count();
    // The predicate Id == 1 and Count() are translated to sql
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It works even without `Cast<>()` here.

Comment: Yes, of course. Obvious, now that I think of it. I'll update the answer.